# find compression mode of JPEG image

Tags: java, jpeg, imaging

I was trying to open jpeg files in a Java program and noticed that neither ImageIO nor the Apache commons imaging library tools could open the images. The commons library showed me this error:

"Only sequential, baseline JPEGs are supported at the moment"

So, my image files are compressed in a way both libraries aren't able to read. I could make an ImageJ macro and transform all the images first but I would like to just use my program and not something extra.

Is there a way to find the compression mode in jpeg or even a java library that can read jpegs in several modes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Libjpeg-turbo](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/code/trunk/java/doc/index.html) could help

Comment: Have you tried using the JAI imageio extension?  http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly it works with the ImageIO standard Class. Don't ask me why. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some tool that will allow you to dump a JPEG stream. There are a number of them out there.

What you are looking for is the start of frame marker.

FFC0 indicates baseline sequential.
FFC1 indicates extended sequential. It doesn't take much more code to do extended sequential than baseline. It is puzzling why a decoder would limit itself to baseline these day.
FFC2 is progressive.

There are others but those are the only ones you are likely to encounter and are widely supported.

You just need to find a tool that will save in baseline format. Finding one to read the other two formats is easy.